# High CPU usage when some applications start

Tags: cpu

I've been having a rather annoying problem with my CPU lately. When some applications are starting, my cpu usage will jump dramatically. It is particularly bad when starting the Java version of Minecraft, and while the game is starting my computer is completely unusable for 30-60 seconds until the main menu loads. My CPU usage quickly jumps from about 15% to 100%, then while the game is running back down to about 20%.

I've tried cleaning the dust out of my computer, and heat doesn't seem to be the issue. Using RealTemp, the cores are not overheating by any means. While idle, all four cores hover around 45°C. To check the high load heat, I messed around in a video editor to keep the CPU at 100% for about 10 minutes, and the temperature never went above 68°C.

Strangely, this high load doesn't seem to happen with all applications. It is by far most noticeable with Minecraft, but i've also seen it with Firefox, and even when opening task manager the usage is briefly 100%. On the other hand, I can simultaneously start Doom Eternal or Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 while using Firefox on my second monitor without a hiccup.

About the processor itself, it's somewhat old but should still be plenty powerful enough to run windows 10 and a couple applications. Intel Core i5-2310 @ 2.90 GHz, Quad-Core. I've also got 16 GB of RAM, which is very rarely fully utilized, and an NVidia GeForce GTX 970.

For a temporary fix, is there any way to throttle how much processing power one application can use? I tried changing the affinity of the applications via Task Manager to only use 3 cores, which seemed to help a little bit. However, I don't know how to do this automatically, as by the time I can change the affinity manually it's mostly loaded and of no use.

Comment: from an admin command prompt run: `wpr -start GeneralProfile` launch the game or whatever causes the CPU issue then, after around 30 seconds run: `wpr -stop C:\gp.etl`.  You can then either: Zip up the file and link it here or download Windows Performance Analyzer from the Store and analyze the trace file.